# Weird grey background on checkbox

Tags: c#

I am creating an application for a new RPG that I am creating. The application has a specific theme and I want to change the checkboxes and buttons to black and the cyan color I chose. On loading the form I use the following code to change the color of the boxes.

```cs
coloredCheckBoxes.Add(checkBox1);
coloredCheckBoxes.Add(checkBox2);
foreach (CheckBox checkBox in coloredCheckBoxes)
{
    checkBox.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
    checkBox.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 1;
    checkBox.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 211, 211);
    checkBox.FlatAppearance.CheckedBackColor = Color.Black;
    checkBox.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.Black;
    checkBox.FlatAppearance.CheckedBackColor = Color.Black;
    checkBox.BackColor = Color.Black;
}
```

No matter how many colors I change the back color of the check boxes still remain this weird grey color.
[image: AppScreenshot]
The check boxes also become lighter if I move my cursor over the boxes as if `checkBox.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.Black;` was not used. Is there a way to fix this issue hopefuly without creating a custom checkbox class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand what you need finally.(I remove any old answer)

Try this,
 - [MetroFramework UI - Original by Peter](https://github.com/peters/winforms-modernui).
 - [MetroFramework UI - Forked, dennismagno(Recommand)](https://github.com/dennismagno/metroframework-modern-ui).
 - [MetroFramework UI - Forked, thielj](https://thielj.github.io/MetroFramework/).

Also provided source code, so you can modify it.
[image]

Comment: This just turns the background white. I think there is more going on than just the `BackColor` property that is effecting the final color.

Comment: I attached image but somehow I don't understand what you need exactly. Is it correct? But you're idea is correct, a box color depends on `BackColor`.

Comment: There was missunderstood. OP need a way to set color without backcolor, is it correct?
I update an answer. 
I could find dependency of backColor for checkBox control.
But I could not find advice for OP's. So, my answer is not for him.

Comment: @jornathan I want the background of the checkbox black hence all the color properties being set to black. If I leave them to default and have back color transparent the checkboxes are white, not black. [Here is an image](https://imgur.com/a/adYoEBx)